# Calculate Euclidean distance for every row with every other row in a NxM matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix that I generate from a CSV file as follows:

```
X = xlsread('filename.csv');
```

I am looping through the matrix based on the number of records and I need to find the Euclidean distance for each of the rows of this matrix :

```
for i = 1:length(X)
 j = X(:, [2:5])
end
```

The resulting matrix is of 150 X 4. What would be the best way to calculate the Euclidean distance of each row (with 4 columns as the data points) with every row and getting an average of the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the Euclidean distance between any pair of rows, you could use the function [pdist](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist.html).

```
X = randn(6, 4);
D = pdist(X,'euclidean');
res=mean(D);
```

The average is stored in `res`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to directly get the average value of whatever we obtain in D?

Comment: Note: This requires the Statistics Toolbox.